# How I retrieve data from SQLite DB in a ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Below is the coding from where   I  retrieved the  data  ?

```
    public String getData() {
    String column[]={id,enter_name,enter_rank};
    Cursor c=sqldatabase.query(table_name, column, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result="";
    int iid=c.getColumnIndex(id);
    int iname=c.getColumnIndex(enter_name);
    int irank=c.getColumnIndex(enter_rank);
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        result=result + " " + c.getString(iid) + " " +c.getString(iname) +" " +c.getString(irank) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

And  Want to show  above retrieved  data in ListView in following  activity

```
  public class SqlView extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextView tv;
  public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    super.onCreate(saved);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sql_view);

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.get_info);

    CheckData check=new CheckData(SqlView.this);

    check.open();
     String info=check.getData();
      check.close();
     tv.setText(info);
  }


    }
```

Comment: You should return the Cursor or an Arraylist of objects instead of one long string. A ListView can't do much with a string

Comment: Related:  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter